# Comparing ArrayList and 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need some help, I have a program that prompts the user to enter a 7-digit number, and then based on the number given the program generates a list of possible word combinations.

So i declared this 2D array:

```
public static final String[][] letter ={
        {"","",""},   //if user enters 0
        {"","",""}, //1
        {"A","B","C"},  //2
        {"D","E","F"},  //3
        {"G","H","I"},  //4
        {"J","K","L"},  //5
        {"M","N","O"},  //6
        {"P","R","S"},  //7
        {"T","U","V"},  //8
        {"W", "X","Y"}  //9
```

And then I generated this method to run through all of the possible word/letter combinations:

```
private static void writeOutputToString(){
        looper = new int[Utilities.numberLength];
        int upper = Utilities.letter[0].length-1, lower =0;
        for(looper[0]=lower; looper[0] <= upper; looper[0]++){
            for(looper[1]=lower; looper[1] <= upper; looper[1]++){
                for(looper[2]=lower; looper[2] <= upper; looper[2]++){
                    for(looper[3]=lower; looper[3] <= upper; looper[3]++){
                        for(looper[4]=lower; looper[4] <= upper; looper[4]++){
                            for(looper[5]=lower; looper[5] <= upper; looper[5]++){
                                for(looper[6]=lower; looper[6] <= upper; looper[6]++){
                                    for(int count = looper.length-1; count >=0; --count){

                                        list.add(Utilities.letter[numbers[count]][looper[count]]);
                                        counter++;
```

Im currently using stringToWrite += "\n"; after counter to make a new line after each word is made, but it keeps putting a comma between each letter and I'm not sure how to fix it! And list is the ArrayList i declared to hold the words. The class Utilities hold the 2D array above!

Additionally I'm reading in a textfile that has all the words in the dictionary one over top of one another (only a single column) as an ArrayList becasue I don't know how many values there are in the file.

```
private static Scanner x;
    private static ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();

        public static void openFile(){
            try{
                x = new Scanner(new File("E:\\dictionary.txt"));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("could not find file");
            }
        }


        public static void readFile(){
            while(x.hasNext()){ //going to loop as long as there is something else

                dictionary.add(x.next());

            }
        }
```

What i need to do next is compare the words I generate from the 7-digit number and compare then to the list of words in the dictionary. If any of the words match then I need to output those to a textfile output.txt. I am stuck and have no idea what to do, if anyone has any help that would roc, or atleast some example code to help me figure out where to go!

Comment: Please do something with these `for` loops :_(

Comment: Your dictionary reading can be also shrunk down with `java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines()`

Comment: the for loops are unnecessary - you do not need those 6... you can just have a for loop that goes from 0 to 6 and then another that uses the integer in the first for loop

Answer (score 0):

Use a hashset to store the dictionary entries

```
HashSet<String> dictionary=new HashSet<String>();
for (String s : Files.readAllLines()) {
   dictionary.add(s);
}
```

then you can check each word in your list with `HashSet.contains()`

```
for (String s : list) {
    if (dictionary.contains(s)) {
        //output to textfile...
    }
}
```